# Advantages when using ActiveJob with Sidekiq compare with Sidekiq alone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm reading some tutorials online that tell us using ActiveJob with Sidekiq. But I don't know why we should do that. I see that Sidekiq has all features that ActiveJob has.

Moreover, on Sidekiq document: [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job)

> Warning: by doing job retry through ActiveJob, you lose a lot of
>   Sidekiq functionality:
>
> 1. Web UI visibility (the Retries tab will be empty)
> 2. You cannot iterate through retries with the Sidekiq::RetrySet API.
> 3. Sidekiq's log will not contain any failures or backtraces.
> 4. Errors will not be reported to Sidekiq's global error handlers
> 5. Many advanced Sidekiq features (e.g. Batches) will not work with AJ retries.

That is a signal somehow make me think that we shouldn't use Sidekiq with ActiveJob. Do I understand wrong about ActiveJob ? Are there any advantages when using ActiveJobs with sidekiq ?

Thanks

Comment: That wiki page is simply telling you not to use ActiveJob's retry, that's all. It doesn't tell you not to use ActiveJob.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks so much. based on your comment and Tony Vincent answer, I can understand a picture. In your opinion, do you prefer using ActiveJob on top of SIdekiq? (because in this case, we must accept some weak point in this solution) such as retry jobs. thanks

Comment: I use ActiveJob over sidekiq, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From rails ActiveJob [guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html)

> The main point is to ensure that all Rails apps will have a job
>   infrastructure in place. We can then have framework features and other
>   gems build on top of that, without having to worry about API
>   differences between various job runners such as Delayed Job and
>   Resque. Picking your queuing backend becomes more of an operational
>   concern, then. And you'll be able to switch between them without
>   having to rewrite your jobs.

basically what ActiveJob does is standardising the API interface for job queuer. This  will help you to change from one job backend to the other with ease.

When you use Sidekiq with ActiveJob, you can benefit from the goodies sidekiq has to offer, but the real catch is when you find another queuer is best for your application, ActiveJob allows you to switch to your job queuer of choice with a one liner

```
# application.rb
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

Comment: thanks so much. But how about some disadvantages such retry jobs (mentions in sidekiq document) if we use ActiveJob on top of sidekiq. Do you think we should prefer using ActiveJob in this case (and lost some other useful features)? thanks.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự It is totally up to you to decide. Ask yourself do you really need Sidekiq's retry tab ? Do you need Sidekiq batch processing etc.. If the answer is yes go with sidekiq, after all sidekiq is a well maintained project

Comment: @TrầnKimDự If you are deploying to heroku, you can use suckerpunch on the same server as the app but sidekiq requires another worker.

Answer (score 8):

As for me, the main feature of ActiveJob is support of GlobalId. Compare:

**Sidekiq**:

```
class SomeJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(record_id)
    record = Record.find(record_id)
    record.do_something
  end
end
SomeJob.perform_async(record.id)
```

**ActiveJob**:

```
class SomeJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(record)
    record.do_something
  end
end

SomeJob.perform_later(record)
```

So convenient and much cleaner!

Sidekiq's retries are supported by ActiveJob since [Sidekiq 6.0](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/6.0-Upgrade.md)

Answer (score 3):

Active Job is an abstraction layer on top of queueing technologies.

In theory, it allows you to program to a common interface, regardless of what you use underneath.

Sounds great right? Well, in practice, it can be much better to use Sidekiq directly.

- Most Ruby/Rails shops are all-in on Sidekiq. You'll never swap Sidekiq for some other queue tech, and in the unlikely event that you do, Active Job won't save you as much work as you think.
- [Sidekiq and Active Job don't work well together](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#commercial-features). It's even worse in older versions. Sidekiq retries don't work out of the box with Active Job unless you're on Rails 6.0.2+ and Sidekiq 6.0.4. And if you're on a version of Rails before 5.1, retries won't work at all via Active Job unless you reinvent the wheel with Sidekiq middleware or adding yet another third party dependency that you don't really need.
- [Active Job adds a lot of overhead](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#performance), and that's just performance overhead captured in benchmarks. More importantly, there's also the cognitive overhead of having to understand how Active Job works in addition to understanding how Sidekiq works. More layers is more complexity, even if it doesn't look like it.
- You lose visibility on retries and errors, since Active Job has its own retry mechanism. They only become visible in Sidekiq once Active Job retries have exhausted and bubble up the exception to Sidekiq.
- The GlobalId feature that Lev mentions? That kind of magic leads to more detective work. Prefer explicit code, rather than hiding behaviour to save one line and misunderstand what the code is actually doing.